# why does 10/NULL evaluate to null?

Tags: sql, rdbms

In SQL , why does 10/NULL evaluate to NULL (or unknown) ? Example :

```
if((10/NULL) is NULL)
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("Null.");
```

However , `1 = NULL` being a COMPARISON is considered as FALSE. Shouldn't 10/NULL also be considered as FALSE ?

I am referring to SQL only . Not any DBMS in particular. And it might be a duplicate but I didn't know what keywords to put in search for this query.

Comment: `1 = NULL` is unknown not false.

Comment: 1 = unknown , which implies `False`.

Comment: No it doesn't imply false. `NOT (1 = NULL)` is not true.

Comment: unknown does not always imply false.

Comment: @sTEAK: `UNKNOWN` does not imply `FALSE`. You are confused because in `WHERE` clauses,, a row passes `WHERE condition` when condition is `TRUE` only and fails when it is FALSE or UNKNOWN.

Comment: But , 1 = unknown is a comparison which need not be true , anything which need not to be true is considered false. I read this in some random book.

Comment: SQL uses a [3-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). Anything that is not TRUE, is either FALSE or UNKNOWN.

Comment: Why do you need 10/NULL anyway? Such operations are not expected in real world applications. And lets consider SQL is wrong, what answer you are expecting? and WHY?

Comment: @AkashKava Just for concept's sake ! Obviously I wouldn't do 10/NULL in any real word app.

Comment: Also, ((1 = NULL) = false) is false rather than true, even though ((1 = NULL) = true) is also false.

Comment: @sTEAK., so SQL guys would not care for concept, neither anyone will, also I think there is an answer already, any arithmetic operation including null will evaluate to null.

Comment: @AkashKava i just wanted to know why are they being evaluated that way and i never mentioned `SQL is wrong` !! I clearly wrote what i expected and why but it seems you didn't read it at all. And it turned out LATER what i was assuming was incorrect and i have already accepted that answer in case you didn't notice.

Comment: @marlin Warning: Nulls and 3-valued logic is tricky. `NOT (1 = NULL)` is not true. It is not false either!

Comment: ~ypercube that type of thing is what I was getting at.  I admit I should have said "Also, ((1 = NULL) = false) is untrue (fails in if and is NULL) rather than true, even though ((1 = NULL) = true) is also the same."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Shouldn't 10/NULL also be considered as FALSE?*

No, because:

> *Any arithmetic expression containing a null **always evaluates to null**. For example, null added to 10 is null. In fact, all operators (except concatenation) return null when given a null operand.*

Emphasis mine, taken from the Oracle manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements005.htm#i59110

And this is required by the SQL standard.

**Edit**, as the question was for RDBMS in general:

### SQL Server

> *When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, an operator that has one or two NULL expressions returns UNKNOWN*

[Link to the the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

### MySQL

> *An expression that contains NULL always produces a NULL value unless otherwise indicated in the documentation for a particular function or operator*

[Link to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/functions.html)

### DB2

> *if either operand can be null, the result can be null, and if either is null, the result is the null value*

[Link to the manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html):

### PostgreSQL

Unfortunately I could not find such an explicit statement in the PostgreSQL manual, although I sure it behaves the same.

---

Warning: The *"(except concatenation)"* is an Oracle only and non-standard exception. (The empty string and NULL are almost identical in Oracle). Concatenating nulls gives null in all other DBMS.

Comment: if there are 4 varchars , var1='abc' , var2 ='' , var3=null , var4 ='123' , and I do var1+var2+var3+var4 , What should be the output?

Comment: @sTEAK. In standard SQL `||` is the string concatenation operator. Concatenating null should yield null.

Comment: @MartinSmith But it says `In fact, all operators (except concatenation) return null when given a null operand.`

Comment: What says that? SQL Server has a `CONCAT` function that implicitly converts nulls to empty string but using `+` to concatenate strings will yield null (except if the deprecated `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` option is used)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Oracle is rather, hmm, un-standard about the empty string (empty string, what empty string?)

Comment: @MartinSmith , The current answer says so. It is mentioned in this link : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements005.htm#i59110

Answer (score 1):

1 = null is not null. It is actually unknown. As well as any other null operation.

Answer (score 1):

The equality predicate `1 = NULL` evaluates to NULL.  But `NULL` in a boolean comparison is considered false.

If you do something like `NOT( 1 = NULL )`, `1 = NULL` evaluates to `NULL`, `NOT( NULL )` evaluates to `NULL` and so the condition as a whole ends up evaluating to false.

Oracle has a section in their documentation on [handling NULL values in comparisons and conditional statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/02_funds.htm#4107)-- other databases will handle things in an very similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

10/something means that you are counting how much "something" will be in 10
in this case you're counting how much "nothing" will be in 10 - that's infinity, unknown..
1 = NULL is false because one does not equal nothing

The NULLIF function accepts two parameters. If the first parameter is equal to the second parameter, NULLIF returns Null. Otherwise, the value of the first parameter is returned.
NULLIF(value1, value2)

NVL
The NVL function accepts two parameters. It returns the first non-NULL parameter or NULL if all parameters are NULL.

also check this conditional outcomes:

This "null equals UNKNOWN truth value" proposition introduces an inconsistency into SQL 3VL. One major problem is that it contradicts a basic property of nulls, the property of propagation. Nulls, by definition, propagate through all SQL expressions. The Boolean truth values do not have this property. Consider the following scenarios in SQL:1999, in which two Boolean truth values are combined into a compound predicate. According to the rules of SQL 3VL, and as shown in the 3VL truth table shown earlier in this article, the following statements hold:

( TRUE OR UNKNOWN ) → TRUE

( FALSE AND UNKNOWN ) → FALSE

However, because nulls propagate, treating null as UNKNOWN results in the following logical inconsistencies in SQL 3VL:

( TRUE OR NULL ) → NULL ( = UNKNOWN )

( FALSE AND NULL ) → NULL ( = UNKNOWN )

The SQL:1999 standard does not define how to deal with this inconsistency, and results could vary between implementations. Because of these inconsistencies and lack of support from vendors the SQL Boolean datatype did not gain widespread acceptance. Most SQL DBMS platforms now offer their own platform-specific recommendations for storing Boolean-type data.
Note that in the PostgreSQL implementation of SQL, the null value is used to represent all UNKNOWN results and the following evaluations occur:

( TRUE OR NULL ) → TRUE

( FALSE AND NULL ) → FALSE

( FALSE OR NULL ) IS NULL → TRUE

( TRUE AND NULL ) IS NULL → TRUE